# multidimensional array indexOf not working js

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexof

I'm trying to find an index of a number in a 2d array, but console gives out

Uncaught TypeError: block[((a * 10) + c)].indexOf is not a function

I think it has something to do with the way of accessing the array element, but can't seem to find the problem.

Here's the code.

```
var block = [];
var temp;
var del;

for(var a = 0;a < 9;a++){
    for(var b = 0;b < 9;b++){
        temp = parseInt(prompt("enter element number " + b + " of row number " + a));
        console.log(temp);
        if(temp>0){
            block[a*10+b] = temp;
        }else{
            block[a*10+b] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
        }
//      console.log(block[a*10+b]); 
    }
}
for(var a = 0;a < 9;a++){
    for(var b = 0;b < 9;b++){
        if(typeof(block[a][b]) == "number"){
            for(var c = 0;c < 9;c++){
                if(c != b){
                    del = block[a*10+c].indexOf(b);
                    block[a*10+c].splice(del,1);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: First, I would do: `console.log(block[((a * 10) + c)])` to see what this is.  But, more specifically, the error you are getting indicates that the value is probably an object and objects do not have an `indexOf` method...Strings do, but you probably don't have a string stored. Also, remember that ALL data returned from a `prompt` is returned as a string. Even if a number was typed in.

Comment: numbers don't have an indexOf() method

Comment: You aren't creating a multi–dimensional array, *block* is just a plain array. The first loop inserts elements at indexes 0 to 99 in a  way that could be done in a single loop from 0 to 99. Only if you enter a negative value will an element of *block* be an array, you likely want `typeof block[a][b]  != "number"`. But then you access `block[a*10+c]`.

Comment: I am creating an multidimensional array.Look at the 12 line.Whenever the input's nan,it turns a*10+b element of block into an array

Comment: I dont know if this will help, but I just tried to replace `parseInt(prompt("....."));` with `5` and I didn't get any errors

Comment: Indeed, @AshotTarumyan, in *that* case it is a nested array, but not when the input is a valid number. In that case you assign that number, and *not*  an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mix of data types assigned to the *block* array. When the user enters a value that is not numeric, you assign indeed a nested array to one of the *block* elements, but not so when the user enters a valid number.

From what I think you are doing (a Sudoko game?) this might be intended: the numbers are known values in the grid, the nested arrays represent a list of values that are still possible at that particular cell.

But then in the second part of your code, you should check in which of the two cases you are, as you only want to remove array elements if the value you are looking at is indeed an array. This test you can do with `Array.isArray()`.

There are also some other issues in the second part of your script:

- The expression `block[a][b]` is not consistent with how you have filled that array: it should be `block[a*10+b]` to be consistent.
- the `b` in `.indexOf(b)` is wrong: you are not looking for that value, but for `block[a*10+b]`.
- the `splice()` is always executed, even if the `indexOf` returned `-1`. This leads to an undesired effect, because if the first argument to `splice()` is negative, the index really is counted from the end of the array, and still an element is removed from the array. This should not happen: you should only execute the `splice` if the `indexOf` result is non-negative.

Below I have put a working version, but in order to avoid the almost endless prompts, I have provided this snippet with a textarea where you can input the complete 9x9 grid in one go, and then press a button to start the execution of your code:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
    var block = [];
    var temp;
    var del;
    var text = document.querySelector('textarea').value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    for(var a = 0;a < 9;a++){
        for(var b = 0;b < 9;b++){
            temp = parseInt(text[a*9+b]); // <-- get char from text area
            if(temp>0){
                block[a*10+b] = temp;
            }else{
                block[a*10+b] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
            }
        }
    }
    for(var a = 0;a < 9;a++){
        for(var b = 0;b < 9;b++){
            var num = block[a*10+b]; // <-- get content, fix the index issue
            if(typeof num == "number"){
                for(var c = 0;c < 9;c++){
                    if(c != b && Array.isArray(block[a*10+c])){ //<-- add array-test
                        del = block[a*10+c].indexOf(num); // <-- not b, but num
                        if (del > -1) // <-- only splice when found 
                            block[a*10+c].splice(del,1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    document.querySelector('pre').textContent = 'block='+ JSON.stringify(block);
};
```

```html
<textarea rows=9>
53..7....
6..195...
.98....6.
8...6...3
4..8.3..1
7...2...6
.6....28.
...419..5
....8..79
</textarea>
<button>Process</button>
<pre></pre>
```

Note that there are elements in `block` which remain `null`. I suppose you intended this: as you multiply `a` with 10, and only store 9 values per "row", there is always one index that remains untouched.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm just new to programming, so i made big mistakes. And yes, its a sudoku solver.

Comment: You're wecome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked over your second `for` loop, but you can try applying similar logic there as in the snippet I've provided. The issue is that you need to create a temporary array inside the outer `for` loop over values of `a` (but NOT inside the inner, nested `for` loop over values of `b`). Inside the `for` loop for values of `b`, then, you need to `push` something into that temporary array (which I called `temp`). Then, outside of the `b` `for` loop, but before the next iteration of `a`, push that temporary array `temp` to the `block` array. In this way, you will generate a 2D array.

```js
var block = [];
var del;

for(var a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
  let temp = [];
  for(var b = 0; b < 9; b++) {
    let num = parseInt(prompt(`Enter element ${b} of row ${a}:`));
    if (num > 0) {
      temp.push(num);
    } else {
      // block[a*10+b] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
      temp.push(b);
    }
  }
  block.push(temp);
}
```